# How do i add values to an array in a GUI

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

I have a GUI that has a input value field at the top with a button to add the value to the array. The array is below it in the form of 10 empty jTextboxes labeled 0-9. When the user enters a number in the value text box and clicks add the number is put into the textfields below. Once the array is populated I will find the minimum and maximum values.
  I have no problem with the logic behind the sort, the find minimum, find maximum values, but I am having a hard time with the logic behind loading the array, I tried to use a couple of different tactics.

```
//This is my start of the on_click event for the add button

jTextboxValue.getText();  //I know that this gets me the text from the box
jTextboxvalueArray0.setText();  // I know this is how I set the text in the various boxes
```

My question is this, what is the most concise way to instantiate and load this array, if it were a console app I would do something like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int array[] = new int[10];

System.out.println("Please enter your Values.");

       for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
       int next = input.nextInt();
```

Now when it comes to doing this within a GUI I am stumped, and this has been a recurring source of confusion for me for some time now. I have read the oracle tutorials, a couple java books but nothing has clicked yet.
   How do I transfer my logic from working in the console to working in a GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. Consider using an array of JTextFields (what is a JTextBox anyway?), say called textFields.
2. Give your gui an int index variable that is initialized to 0.
3. When the user enters a number into the entry field and presses the correct button, get the text from the input JTextField via `getText()`, put it into a local String variable,
4. then pass that variable into the `setText(text)` method of the index item of the textFields array, `textFields[index].setTexzt(text)`.
5. Increment the index variable, `index++`.

Note: why not simply let the user enter all their numbers ***directly*** into each JTextField of the textFields array, and then have them press the evaluate JButton when done? Why try to stuff the JTextFields yourself as state is your goal? That seems kind of a kludge to me.

Comment: if I take the input from the textfield and store it in a string variable, do I have to tokenize it before casting to ints and passing to my array?

Comment: @Guyute: I'm saying have 10 JTextFields (again, do not call them JTextBoxes as this animal does not exist and will only serve to confuse us). Have the user enter their numbers, and then push a button. Then you can iterate through the JTextField array (or List as MadProgrammer suggests), extracting text from each field and putting it into your int array or `List<Integer>`. Don't you dare try to cast anything to an int if you want this thing to run. You need to parse it to an int.

Comment: oops, yeah I mean parse not cast, I have to design it in a way that has 1 textfield for input and displays the values in the corresponding textfields when the add value button is pushed. I agree that it is kind of kludgy but that is the requirement. I think that it is also what is hanging me up so much.

Answer (score 1):

Have a single `JTextField` as the primary user input.  Have a `JButton` next to it that acts as the "add" mechanism.

When clicking add, add the value to a `JList` instead.  Don't focus so much on the array, as it's just getting in your way.  You can manage the `JList`'s model to determine when you have what ever limit of numbers you need/want (if you need/want one).

See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details